"toy animals" VS "animal toys"

There are plenty of animal toys, as always, for the younger children. BBC - Christmas 1952

The use of animal toys caught my attention, as I thought it meant toys for animals to play with.
As a non-native speaker, I would have thought toy animals would have been the correct usage. So, I was left in confusion, and I checked ngram, and toy animals are shown a lot higher in graphic.
However, since it is the BBC, I think it might still be true, so I got confused.
Are both OK?

A toy animal is always a toy which is made to resemble an animal, but an animal toy could be either: a toy which is made to resemble an animal, or something (e.g. a rubber bone, cloth mouse, ball) intended to given to a pet for it to play with.

It's less usual to put it that way round, but she is referring to 'animal toys' as one category of toys. The context makes it clear that they are toys for children.

I've never heard anyone call a toy animal an animal toy in AmE. Does this reversal happen in BrE?

Actually, I am aware of "toy animal" being used for small animals, "toy poodle" for example. I've also seen the like applied to very small pigs and I believe horses.

Perhaps "the younger children" are still teething and would enjoy a doggie chew toy ;-)

The story is about Christmas gifts to children. So even though this isn't the normal phrase, it's easily understood in context.

@TimR - I would say 'toy animal' and 'animal toy' are interchangeable in BrE Shop animal toys for toddlers at Talking Turtle. Explore zoo, farm, mini animals & realistic figures that inspire creative play and learning. Free 1-day delivery over £25,  ‎14-day returns and Crafted with the assistance of UK teachers, our bespoke animal toys are tailored towards bringing fun and play together for a touch of monkey madness. but... Toy Animals & Environments ... Perfect for early years, our animals & environment range is ideal to teach children about new animals and the environment they live

@TimR - I think in the UK a rubber monkey or plush bear for a toddler could be called either a toy animal or an animal toy without frightening any UK [toy] horses. I think a cloth mouse filled with catnip for my cat might be more likely classified as an animal toy but it is, of course, still a toy animal. I think someone working in a toy store might put 'toy' last because they classify: animal toys, construction toys, educational toys, puzzle toys, ride-on toys (etc etc etc).

@TimR - I was once reminded by a relative of my best friend when I was two, who was called 'Wubber Monkey'. Woe betide anyone who called him a 'toy', apparently.

@DrMoishePippik - at the age of 3 I tried my grandmother's collie's biscuits and lived to tell the tale.
